# Why navigator.MediaDevices is undefined in extension's page injected script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm writing an extension for chrome which has to take a video record of a current tab. So I've wrote a script injector, it works fine. But when I'm trying to get navigator.MediaDevices it returns `undefined`. According to docs it is correct behavior for insecure context. Yet I'm executing it on `https` tabs, so I think it's something extension specific and maybe MV3. Also I've tried to play around with permissions in manifest, can't figure it out.

UPD:
Tried from localhost, same result.

Code:

```
async function contScript(){
    const res = await execOnCurrTab(() => {
        const nav = navigator;
        const MD  = nav.MediaDevices;
        const MS  = MD.getDisplayMedia();
    });
}

function execOnCurrTab(callback){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
            let tab = tabs[0];
            chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                {
                    target: { tabId: tab.id },
                    function: callback,
                    args: [tab.title],
                },
                (injectionResults) => {
                    const injRes = injectionResults[0].result;
                    console.log(injRes)
                    testObj = {
                        'res' : injRes
                    }
                    resolve(injRes);
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
"permissions": [
  "desktopCapture",
  "activeTab",
  "storage",
  "notifications",
  "alarms",
  "scripting"
],
```

Comment: Replace `M` with `m` so it becomes `navigator.mediaDevices`

Comment: That's actually the solution. Much thx.